# Is there a way to edit a script with multiple parameters

Tags: linux, bash

I have created a bash script template that has 3 variables set at the top:

```
parameter="LogLevel" value="VERBOSE" file="/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
```

However, I have a huge list of parameters with different values and want to create a separate script for each parameter.

For example:

```
#1 filename1, parameter1, value1
#2 filename2, parameter2, value2
#3 filename3, parameter3, value3
so on ..
```

Now I want a way to populate my template with all these different values: to create a script for each parameter.

So it would be like

- script1 for #1
- script2 for #2
- and so on.

Side note:
The script goes into file and search for parameter and replaces the value.

Comment: I do not understand. `I want a way to populate my template` What does it mean to "populate my template" _exactly_? Do you want to create some files? You want to print to the screen? Are you aware of _positional arguments_ in shell?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes I want to create files. 1 file for 1 parameter/value.

Comment: Since you are using Linux, you should have a programm called `envsubst` , which creates a new file from an existing template file, by replacing variables. While I doubt that it makes much sense what you are going to do, at least _envsubst_ should do excactly what you are asking for.

Comment: If you want to work with templates for system configurations, you may have a look at dedicated admin tools like ansible that are exactly designed for such kind of tasks. Then it may be more appropriate to ask in SuperUser for example.

Comment: @LéaGris Can you share any document for doing that using Ansible? I want to create 100 scripts with 100 parameters by replacing a particular field in 1 file.

Comment: But... why not make a _generic_ one script that takes any input?

Comment: @KamilCuk The requirements are such that I need a separate file for each parameter.

Comment: Requirement (What was written on a bit of paper), or a constrain (what some legacy system needs)?

Comment: `I need a separate file for each parameter` Sure, sooo have a separate files that all call one master script? I still do not understand what should the contents of that file be _exactly_ or what specification those files have to follow. What do the scripts do? Can you give an actual example to the meaning of the parameters and function of the scripts? Where from comes the requirement of separate files? What is the context? `I have a huge list of parameters` Where and in what format is that "huge list" stored? You seem to be asking a very narrow XY question, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

No need for cut and paste programming.

Change line one to `file="$1" parameter="$2" value="$3"`

Then create the separate scripts

script1

```
script filename1 parameter1 value1
```

script2

```
script filename2 parameter2 value2
```

Comment: I need a separate script for each. That is why I've designed it this way.

Comment: @VikasGothwal I made a change.